# SQL timestamp Query

Tags: sql

Table has `Created_time` column with values like `25-MAY-2012.10.12.320000 PM`.

I need to write a query to display the all the fields from `table` XYZ which were created between the  month of `March` and `April`, agnostic to the year they are in.

I would like to display the records in ascending order based on their id.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is the data type of column created_time?

Comment: What have you tried, this isn't a homework site

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: CREATED_TIME NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using! When it comes to date/time many products are fare from ANSI SQL compliant. The timestamp used above is not the ANSI SQL format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out month and year function.
if created_time is of type datetime:

```
select * 
from TABLE 
where month(Created_time) in (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check whether the `Created_time` was in March of any year, then the idea is to do something like this:

```
select *
from XYZ
where Created_time like '%-MARCH-%'
order by id;
```

Or, if this is not supported for your `column`'s type, then convert it to `varchar`. Also, there are some RDBMS-specific `function`s that could help you, but for a more thorough answer I would need to know the RDBMS you are using and the `type` of `Created_time`.

EDIT

As pointed out by Jarhl, EXTRACT should be usable in this case to check the month. [Source](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/re84.html), proving that he is right says:

> Name
>
> EXTRACT
>
> The ANSI SQL scalar function for extracting parts from a date is
>   EXTRACT. ANSI SQL Standard Syntax
>
> The ANSI SQL EXTRACT function takes a date_part and an expression that
>   evaluates to a datetime value. MySQL, Oracle, and PostgreSQL support
>   the ANSI SQL standard syntax:
>
> `EXTRACT( date_part FROM expression )`

Comment: According to a comment the Created_time data type is TIMESTAMP(6).

Comment: @jarlh thank you for pointing that out. I might be wrong but I think precision like that can be given in Oracle. In that case conversion to textual data can be done using to_char. However, if we are in Oracle, then EXTRACT can be used to get the month. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: EXTRACT is even the ANSI SQL function to be used in cases like this! (But the timestamp specified in the question is not ANSI SQL compliant, so who knows which dbms OP is using...)

Comment: @jarlh thank you again, I have edited my answer to reflect this information.